# C sizeof((x)) not working when I pass x as a pointer

Tags: c

When I use the size of function in the main function it works correctly. However when i use it in the reverse function it only returns 8. Any ideas why or did i incorrectly use it.(This is the beginning of a assignment where I must reverse a string passed to the reverse function. I may only pass the string and nothing else and cannot use the string.h library. If there is another way to accomplish this please let me know. I was planning on using the sizeof function to get the size then looping through the array and use a temp variable to reverse it as I loop.)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
char reverse(char *x);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char word[] = "Apple pies";
printf("%s\n", word);
reverse(word);
printf("%s\n", word);
printf("%s\n", reverse(word));
printf("%s\n", word);
return 0;
}
char reverse(char *x)
{
    char crud;
    int lc =0;
    size_t length = 0; 
    char *tmp = x; 
    while (*tmp++) 
    ++length;
    while (length > lc)
    {
        crud = x[length];
        x[length] = x[lc];
        x[lc] =crud;
        length--;
        lc++;

    }
}
```

Comment: In `reverse`, `x` is just a pointer (i.e. `char*`). In `main`, `x` is an array (`char[11]`). That `sizeof` trick only works on arrays, not pointers. You'll have to pass the length to `reverse` as a parameter (or use `strlen`).

Comment: I assume strlen is in the <string.h> library? i need to reverse a string passed to reverse but need to only pass the parameters of (char * x) and cannot use the string.h library

Comment: In that case you have to write your own version of `strlen`. It's easy to do. e.g. `size_t length = 0; while (*x++) ++length;`

Comment: @Cornstalks could you post that as an answer so i can say you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `reverse`, `x` is just a pointer (that is, a `char*`). But in `main`, `x` is an array (that is, a `char[11]`). That `sizeof` trick only works on arrays, not pointers. You'll have to pass the length to `reverse` as a parameter (or use `strlen`). [This is covered in more detail in another question and its answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Since you say `strlen` is forbidden in your situation (as is passing in the length via a parameter), you'll have to implement `strlen` manually. It's trivial:

```
size_t length_of_str(const char *x) {
    size_t length = 0;
    while (*x++) ++length;
    return length;
}
```

Comment: I updated my code. Do you know whats wrong with the reverse function?

Comment: @christian: You should ask a new question rather than changing your current one. Edits are okay to clarify details, but this is kinda fundamentally changing the original question. I'll give you a hint: `x[length]` is not what you think it is (on the very first iteration). If you need further help, I encourage you to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In the main method when you call the sizeof function, you are passing an array. But in the 'reverse' function, the argument is a character pointer. When you call `sizeof` on a pointer, there is no guaranteed result. Often you get 4 when you call `sizeof` on a char pointer. But again, there is no guarantee that sizeof will always return that value. You should not use `sizeof` for pointers.

Comment: When arrays are passed as pointers into functions, `sizeof` only computes the size of the pointer. In general, many functions that manipulate arrays containing binary data also need an explicit length to be passed in.